# How to display data between start date and end date or start time and end time from sql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I develop a web-service and send data from SQL to API. But, is's based on start-date and end-date or start-time and end-time but result not get perfectly.

CakePHP Query Code :

```
$Home = $this->Home->find('all',array(
          'contain' => array('LiveVideo' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                        array('OR' => array('DATE(LiveVideo.from_date) >=' => date('Y-m-d')),
                        array('DATE(LiveVideo.to_date) <=' => date('Y-m-d')))



                        //'LiveVideo.from_time >=' => date('h:i'),
                        //array('LiveVideo.to_time <=' => date('h:i'))

                )

            )),

          'fields' => array(),
          'order' => 'Home.created DESC',             
    ));
```

I want to result between start-date and start-time or end-date and end -time.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most basic question in everyday applications. The answer is best one if question is related only to the database.

As per the tags you have applied i believe it is related to the PHP based dynamic web page. If you are using Core PHP then you can follow following script part that you can just copy and paste. All explanation is there in form of comments :

```
<?php
/**
 * Connect to mysql server from php script
 * Please replace the credentials as per your environment configuration
 * Parameters details :
 * "localhost" -- It is Hostname where mysql server is installed
 * "root" -- Default username for mysql
 * "password" -- Password for MySQL Database user, Can be left blank if there is no password
 * "test" -- It is the database which contains project data
 */ 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "test");
/**
 * Now setting the query parameters
 */
$startDate="2015-01-01";
$endDate="2015-12-31";
/**
 * Lets execute query on MySQL
 * here used columns are
 * OrderDate -- replace it with your date field
 * OrderNo -- replace with fields you want in your results
 * orders -- replace with name of table you want to use 
 */
$mysqli->real_query("
     SELECT OrderDate,OrderNo
     FROM orders
     WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '{$startDate}' AND '{$endDate}'
     ORDER BY OrderDate ASC
");
/**
 * Get result buffer
 */
$res = $mysqli->use_result();

echo "Result from table...<br />";
/**
 * Printing result on web page with while loop
 */
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo " OrderDate = " . $row['OrderDate'] . " OrderNo = " . $row['OrderNo'] . "<br />";
}
```

IN CakePHP

```
<?php

$start = new Time('2018-01-01');
$end = new Time('2018-01-31');

$table = $this->Tables->find('all')
  ->contain(['AssocTables' => function ($q) use ($start, $end){
    return $q->where(['AssocTables.start >=' => $start, 'AssocTables.end <=' => $end])
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct. Just remove the "OR" clause from your query as you want where **(date >= startDate AND date <= endDate)**

Also you need to specify the date format in order to compare the dates with php

```
      $Home = $this->Home->find('all',array(
              'contain' => array('LiveVideo'),
              'conditions' => array('DATE_FORMAT(LiveVideo.from_date, "%Y-%m-%d") >=' => date('Y-m-d'), 'DATE_FORMAT(LiveVideo.to_date, "%Y-%m-%d") <=' => date('Y-m-d')),
              'fields' => array(),
              'order' => 'Home.created DESC',             
  );
```

Comment: Also Compare with time start and end

Comment: What do you want to compare. Pls elaborate

Comment: Compare from_date and to_date, from_time and to_time